# PDO syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO for a project but i have a syntax error on submit... here is my code :

```
<?php

require_once('_database.php');

    $titre = $_POST['titre']; 
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d");

try
{               
    // Insertion dans la base de donnée                         
    $requete = $connexion->exec("INSERT INTO article (id, idAuteur, titre, text, date) VALUES (0, 0, $titre, $text, $date)");           

    if (!$requete) {
       echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
       print_r($connexion->errorInfo());
       echo $requete;
    }

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

And this is what I got in my browser:

```
PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
Your contentrgrgrg

, 2013-12-18)' at line 1 )
```

I suppose I've forgotten something obvious but can't see what...

Comment: Why do you use PDO if you ignore prepared statements...

Comment: You should be using placeholders and bound variables to generate your SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're already using PDO, you should be using parameterized queries with [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

```
$stmt = $connexion->prepare("INSERT INTO article (id, idAuteur, titre, text, date)
    VALUES (0, 0, ?, ?, ?)");           
$stmt->execute(array($titre, $text, $date));
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning: Named placeholders like `:id`. These make the binding calls a lot easier to read.